# Insert a value to SQL Server database with LINQ on C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a code like this

```
MsCustomer mc = new MsCustomer
{
     CustomerID=idBox.Text,
     CustomerName=nameBox.Text,
     CustomerGender=gender,
     CustomerPhone=phoneBox.Text,
     CustomerAddress=addressBox.Text
};
dc.MsCustomers.InsertOnSubmit(mc);
dc.SubmitChanges();                

MessageBox.Show("Insert Success");
generateID();
```

when I execute the program, the data is not really inserted to the SQL Server database so the ID won't generate. If the code is CS003 on database its still CS003. But on the application it's already inserted, so when I insert it again with value CS003 it says can't create duplicate key ID.

Can you guys help me? What's wrong with this code?

here's what i write on generateID()

```
  private string generateID()
    {
        try
        {
            var ID = (from x in dc.MsCustomers
                      orderby x.CustomerID descending
                      select x).First();
            int substring = int.Parse(ID.CustomerID.ToString().Substring(2)) + 1;
            string temp = "CS" + String.Format("{0:000}", substring);

            return temp;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            string first = "C0001";
            return first;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're being told that you're trying to insert a duplicate the second time then obviously the data was inserted the first time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yeah its said im trying to insert a duplicate key, but when i do generateID() , the customer id is still CS003, it should be CS004 because CS003 its already inserted. i try to change copy to output directory to copy always but it has no effect, sorry for bad english :))

Comment: Then your `generateID` method doesn't work.  We know absolutely nothing about that method so we would have to be psychic to be able to know what's wrong with it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your attention, i've updated my post, i already write the generateID()

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible, that your `generateID()` method works flawlessly. What does not make sense in your code is how you use it.

After you inserted data into the database, you just call it. It returns a string and - nothing. Maybe you intended to change the value of the `idBox.Text` property and then insert this value, but you haven't and we don't know, so I am assuming you want `generateID()` to generate the ID for your entity, in which case the idBox itself is obsolet.
In my humble opinion it is almost never a good idea to let the user choose the primary key / id of your data.

What you probably want to accomplish is something along this lines:

```
MsCustomer mc = new MsCustomer
{
     /* new line */
     CustomerID = generateID();
     CustomerName=nameBox.Text,
     CustomerGender=gender,
     CustomerPhone=phoneBox.Text,
     CustomerAddress=addressBox.Text
};
dc.MsCustomers.InsertOnSubmit(mc);
dc.SubmitChanges();                

MessageBox.Show("Insert Success");
```

Comment: yes, i wrote a code just like u did before, but the insert doesnt work,so i think when i put generateid() under submitchanges the database will be refreshed hahaha im a beginner sorry for that.